# something not working in date dropdown, working with php

Tags: php, html, date, drop-down-menu, for-loop

I will keep this as simple as I can.  I am trying to make a dropdown menu for the date.  I have seen several examples similar to this online, however I am having difficulty getting them to work.

here is my code for the dropdown:

```
<?php
$current_month = date('m');
$number_of_day_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $current_month , date('Y'));
?>
Day:<select name="day">
  <?php for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_day_in_month ;$i++):?>
         <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></option>
     <?php endfor?>
</select>

Month: <select name="month">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++):?> 
         <option value="<?=str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)?>"><?=$i?></option>
    <?php endfor?>
</select>
```

I realize that this is not the most effective way to aquire the date, but please work with me.  I am trying to make this stupid proof, which is why I did not make it a simple textbox.  When I run this on a server there is nothing, when I run this on Dreamweavers local workspace it just makes the dropdown box with no values inside.

I have no idea why nothing is showing up.

I appreciate any help that I can get, and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: are you sure that "<?=$i?>" (shorts) works? try "<?php echo $i; ?>"

Comment: I copied your code and tested it through xampp, and finally the Date and Month drop-down select tag works...please check your php version, try to test it out using xampp..just for development use..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
  <?php for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_day_in_month ;$i++){
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
  }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP must use the start tagging.. `<?php` , while older version doesn't require.

Try this code:

```
<?php
$current_month = date('m');
$number_of_day_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $current_month , date('Y'));
?>
Day:<select name="day">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_day_in_month ;$i++) {?>
         <option value="<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $i?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>

Month: <select name="month">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {?> 
            <option value="<?php echo str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)?>"><?php echo $i?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with that cal_days_in_month() function?  You can get the number of days in the month with just date("t"). Also, the `<?= ?>` is going to be deprecated soon in PHP.

```
<select name="day">
<?php for($i=1; $i<=date("t"); $i++): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```